# How can I open all files in a directory with sublime text 2?

Tags: command-line, sublimetext2

I am using windows and have successfully added sublime to the PATH.  It seems that commands like -b for open in background do not work for whatever reason.  My question is how can I open a directory with the command subl ./dir and open each file individually?  Right now it adds it to the project and I would much rather it just open every file separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try

```
> subl dir/*
```

Alternatively, you can open the project in a dir `> subl dir` and then install EnhancedSidebar package in sublime. This allows you to select multiple file right click them and click edit. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Do you have any idea why the -b command wont open a window without stalling the command line in windows?

Comment: And the command opens 2 windows.  Any ideas? The second one shows whatever I previously had open.  Its like it is opening the program and then opening my new stuff

Comment: I am not on windows. But you might be able to use start command to start the app without stalling. `> start subl dir/*`. As for sublime opening the previous windows, that's a feature in sublime, one way you can avoid that is by just closing the project before quitting sublime. Another way is by adding this line to your sublime user settings: `"remember_open_files": false` - User settings should be somewhere in preferences.