# Reindenting all files inside a folder in Sublime

Tags: javascript, html, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-formatting

I have Sublime Text 3 and what i want to do is reindent **all the files inside a folder** I am presently using [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) as my plugin to reindent. So I want to right-click on the folder icon which is on the sidebar and get an option of reindenting all the files inside them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pretty close if you're willing to [write your own plugin](https://clarknikdelpowell.com/blog/creating-sublime-text-3-plugins-part-1/).

The plugin code:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class ReindentAllCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        [v.run_command('htmlprettify') for v in sublime.active_window().views()]
```

This is based on [this response on the Sublime Text forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/apply-operation-to-multiple-files-selected-in-open-files/2432). It runs the `htmlprettify` command in every open file. You could replace that with a different plugin, if you want.

To open all files in a folder, you can follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330827/how-can-i-open-all-files-in-a-directory-with-sublime-text-2).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did which might be a faster less technical solution than creating a plugin code.

1. Open HTMLPretify (PC - Ctrl+Shift+P)
2. Select HTMLPrettify: Set Plugin Options

> ```
> // Automatically format when a file is saved.
> "format_on_save": false,
>
> // Automatically format when a file is opened. (Sublime Text 3 only)
> "format_on_open": false,
> ```

3. Change both of those to TRUE - Save.
4. Open all files - you can do this by CTRL+Shift+F find something all files have in common like  and Replace: with a space in front (this will open all files)

This will take some time depending on how many files you have opened. Then just goto File > Save all.

Upon opening - this will prettify every file.

Comment: unable to find HTMLPretify after pressing Ctrl+Shift+P